# jquery and safari 7 - slideToggle and fadeToggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari

Hi I have quite a bit of jquery on this page homestartpage .com

it all works fine on every browser I've tested it on except the new version of safari.

The issue is when you drag one of the squares on that page, you should notice a little square appear beside the other little blue squares on the top header bar with a trashcan icon in it.

This uses fadeToggle and works on everything except safari 7

The other issue is when you click the right most blue square on header with the icon of a person on it, a drop down menu should appear. This uses slideToggle and again doesn't work on safari 7

Anyone any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Safari on iOS or MacOS?

Comment: It's not me who has the machine and who spotted the problem but he said maverick 10.9 safari 7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the **version 2.0 of jquery**, wich don't support ie8 and before but is more recent. Take a look here http://jquery.com/download/